# How to restrict access to groups and execute code as user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

**Application:**

MVC Website running on IIS 8.5 / Windows Server 2012R2.

**Requirements:**

- Restrict Access to certain user groups
- Execute Code as the user that sends the requests (i.e. querying a Database, accessing files etc.)

**Steps taken so far:**

- Web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>    
  </system.webServer>
```

- IIS > Sites > $TheSiteName$ > Authentication > Disable all except Windows
- IIS > Sites > $TheSiteName$ > Authorization Rules > Allow All
- Active Directory > $TheServerName$ > Delegation > Trust this computer for delegation to any service (Kerberos only)

**Results**

- IIS complains that impersonation is not possible in Integrated Pipeline Mode
- When I change Pipeline Mode to classic, a authentication dialogue pops up, but seems to be inable to verify my credentials.

Any idea what I might have forgotten to get this to work? Why can't I access this website?

Soon as I got this going, I will have to take care of restrictions. Wild guessing as I am, I would assume it will be possible to add the restricted groups into the authorization rules, but I can't get to test it...Is this the right / best way to do that?

Comment: What identity is the Application Pool running as.  When I secure folders like you have, I often forget that if the pool is set as ApplicationPoolIdentity, you need the IIS user group on the folder.  Otherwise, the initial touch of the file system is done by an account that doesn't have access to the folder.

Comment: ApplicationPoolIdentity is the user for the application pool and IIS_IUSRS has full access to the directory the files reside in.

Comment: Load filemon onto your server and then watch the access denials when a request comes in.  You should also see a process in the task manager load up with the user you are impersonating running the w3wp process.